# SAPUI5: Handle click events properly

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sapui5

I am using the SAPUI5 control `GenericTile` and added both `headerImage` and `click` event. When this icon is clicked, the event handler of the tile is triggered first so that I am not able to react on the icon click itself (which should perform another action of course).

```
var oGenericTile = new sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile({
                frameType: "TwoByOne",
                header: "My HEader",
                headerImage: "sap-icon://settings",
                tileContent: oTileContent
            });

oGenericTile._oImage.attachPress(function(oEvent) {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Icon has been pressed");
                oEvent.cancelBubble();
                oEvent.preventDefault();
            });

            oGenericTile.attachPress(function() {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("I am always triggered first!!!   :-(");
            });`
```

Any idea how I can avoid this?

Comment: You need to extend `sap.suite.commons.GenericTile` with your own control, i.e. `my.GenericTile` and override `my.GenericTile.prototype.onclick/ontapstart` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could e.g. also cancel the event on the tile manually in order to avoid this behavior... you'd just need to track whether the icon has been pressed, see a simplified example on JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/daqifomoge/3/edit

Extending existing controls and overriding methods always bears the potential to break things when the original control gets an update from the developers...

Maybe there's a more elegant way to do it, though.

Best,
Christiane